# Javascript button onclick not creating a new record

Tags: javascript, custom-button

i am creating a button which will create new record. this is my code

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")} 


var curnc= new sforce.SObject("TR_Currency_Approval__c"); 
curnc.Name="{!TR_Currency__c.Name}"; 
curnc.Active__c="{!TR_Currency__c.Active__c}"; 
curnc.Description__c="{!TR_Currency__c.Description__c}"; 

var result=sforce.connection.create([curnc]);


if(result[0].success == 'true'){
    alert('An New Currency with Name - ' + TR_Currency__c.Name + ' was Created Successfully.');
}
```

Please let me know any errors,

Comment: I don't see any error. Is it working?

Comment: not working martin, button is not at all responding

Comment: this is not an answer, I think you should try to do it otherwise and avoid using javascript on button click (remember read about it, that is deprecated)

Comment: Try to add a condition if there is no success like this:`if(result[0].success == 'true'){...}else{alert(result[0].errors[0]);}`. Like this you'll be able to get the error message.

Comment: I tried by giving else condition also, not working, please let me know is there any other way to create a new record by onclick of button

Comment: Where is button-click related code? Can you plz update your question and add that part?

Comment: please find the code here

Comment: {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")} 


var curnc= new sforce.SObject("TR_Currency_Approval__c"); 
curnc.Name="{!TR_Currency__c.Name}"; 
curnc.Active__c="{!TR_Currency__c.Active__c}"; 
curnc.Description__c="{!TR_Currency__c.Description__c}"; 

var result=sforce.connection.create([curnc]);


if(result[0].success == 'true'){
    alert('An New Currency with Name - ' + TR_Currency__c.Name + ' was Created Successfully.');
}else {
alert(‘Could not create record’ +result);
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")} 


var curnc = new sforce.SObject("TR_Currency_Approval__c");
curnc.Name="{!TR_Currency__c.Name}"; 
curnc.Active__c="{!TR_Currency__c.Active__c}"; 
curnc.Description__c="{!TR_Currency__c.Description__c}"; 

var result = sforce.connection.create([curnc]);

if(result[0].getBoolean("success")){
    alert('An New Currency with Name - ' + TR_Currency__c.Name + ' was Created Successfully.');  //Opening the record in edit mode if the record insert is successfull
    window.location = "/"  + result[0].id + "/e";   //Opening the record in edit mode if the record insert is successfull
}
else{
    alert('Could not create record' + result);
}
```